# Reactjs routing composed routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having some difficulty with react routing and having trouble comprehending composed routes. I've attempted some code, but unfortunately, it's not functioning as expected. The `"/"` path works perfectly fine, however, when I attempt to access `"/child"`, it doesn't seem to work. I believe there might be an issue with the wrapper route `<Route element={<Wrapper/>} />`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function Home() {
  return <h1>its home</h1>
}

function Child() {
  return <h1>its child</h1>
}

function Wrapper() {
  return( 
    <div>
      <h1>trial</h1>
      <Route path="/child" element={<Child />} />
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route element={<Wrapper />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

- You have defined your `/child` path in the wrong place
- You have placed it inside your `Wrapper` component

### Simple Solution

- This solution just fixes the immediate problem
- The paths should be defined within the `<BrowserRouter> <Routes>`
- See the two commented lines from your example on where to make the changes

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'


function Home(){
    return <h1>its home</h1>
}

function Child(){
    return <h1>its child</h1>
}

function Wrapper(){
    return( 
    <div>
     <h1>trial</h1>
     <Child/> // Use Child component here
    </div>
    )
}

function App(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path= "/home" element={<Home/>} />
                <Route path= "/child" element={<Wrapper/>}  /> //Path here
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

### Further Reading

- As you say you are still a beginner I'd recommend [react router tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial). It will really help your understanding of the router
- In particular see the [Nested Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#nested-routes) section. I believe this is what you are trying to acheive with the "wrapper"?

### Further Solution

- [Live version of solution codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-snow-fvtpqt?file=/src/index.js)
- This solution will make more sense once you have read through the tutorial above.
- Use react-router `Outlet` in your wrapper so you can then use the Wrapper across multiple components

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
}

function Child() {
  return <h2>its child</h2>;
}

function Wrapper() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Wrapper</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/home",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Wrapper />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "child",
        element: <Child />
      }
    ]
  }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you are meaning when you say "composed routes", but React-Router basically has two types of routes.

- Nested Routes: `Route` components ***directly*** rendering other (*e.g nested*) `Route` components.

  ```
  const FooLayout = () => {
    return (
      ...
      <Outlet />
      ...
    );
  };
  ```

  ```
  <Route path="foo" element={<FooLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Foo />} />         // <-- rendered into Outlet
    <Route path="bar" element={<FooBar />} /> // <-- rendered into Outlet
  </Route>
  ```
- Descendent Routes: Routed components rendering another set of `Routes` and `Route` components.

  ```
  const FooWrapper = () => {
    return (
      ...
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Foo />} />       // <-- descendent route
        <Route path="/bar" element={<FooBar />} /> // <-- descendent route
      </Routes>
      ...
    );
  };
  ```

  ```
  <Route path="foo/*" element={<FooWrapper />} /> // <-- renders descendents
  ```

Armed with this knowledge now you have a couple basic ways to render the `Child` component on the `"/child"` path where it's accessible/renderable.

```
function Wrapper() {
  return( 
    <div>
      <h1>trial</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/child" element={<Child />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Wrapper />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

or

```
function Wrapper() {
  return( 
    <div>
      <h1>trial</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route element={<Wrapper />}>
          <Route path="/child" element={<Child />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

For more details see [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets), and [Splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats).